# Password protected page not redirecting correctly when password is supplied

Tags: wordpress, cookies, password-protection

Inherited a site with a convoluted setup.

wp-login.php is served by a different subdomain than the page being password protected. It is also behind https while the password protected page is not.

When the correct password is supplied the form action goes to https://backend.sitename.com/wp-login.php?action=postpass and is redirected back to http://frontend.sitename.com/pagename/ with the password form presented again.

The developer console throws up a few warnings about cookies without a SameSite attribute set.

Not sure on the best way to correct this?

Answer (score 0):

The `SameSite` warnings should only affect cross-site cookies.  `backend.sitename.com` and `frontend.sitename.com` would be considered different subdomains, but still the same site, so that shouldn't be breaking anything.

However, I would suggest looking at a `SameSite=Strict` setting for that cookie. Additionally, migrating to HTTPS is a priority as those HTTP pages can easily have their cookies sniffed and stolen on an open wifi network.

You can find more context on the `SameSite` attribute and the upcoming change at https://web.dev/samesite-cookies-explained